# Kotlin and @Transient

Tags: android, gson, kotlin, realm

hava a class:

```
open class MessageDTO : RealmObject, Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("message_id")
    var messageId: String? = null

    @SerializedName("chat")
    var chat: String? = null

    @SerializedName("chat_type")
    var chatType: String? = null

    @SerializedName("content")
    var content: ContentDTO? = null

    @SerializedName("created")
    var created: Date? = null

    @SerializedName("from")
    var from: String? = null

    @SerializedName("important")
    var important: Boolean? = null

    @SerializedName("is_first")
    var isFirst: Boolean? = null

    @SerializedName("is_group")
    var isGroup: Boolean? = null

    @SerializedName("is_last")
    var isLast: Boolean? = null

    @SerializedName("linked_messages")
    var linkedMessages: RealmList<MessageDTO>? = null

    @SerializedName("links")
    var links: RealmList<ModelLinks>? = null

    @SerializedName("read")
    var read: Boolean? = null

    @SerializedName("to")
    var to: String? = null

    @Ignore
    var displayName: String? = null

    @Ignore
    var authorPhoto: ModelIcons? = null

    @Transient
    var deliveredToServer: Boolean = false
```

and need to use `@Transient` with variable `deliveredToServer`
but have compile error:

> e: error: Class "MessageDTO" contains illegal transient field
>   "deliveredToServer". e:
>
> e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze:
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while
>   annotation processing

what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you try `@field:[Transient]` to see if it works?

Comment: What version of Realm is this?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce `3.1.3`

Comment: @Joshua I will try it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Transient fields were not supported in 3.1.3 and had to be explicitly ignored with `@Ignore`.

See the change log.

> 3.2.0 (2017-05-16)
>
> Transient fields are now allowed in model classes, but are implicitly treated as having the @Ignore annotation (#4279).